# Can a Certificate Authority be blocked?

Tags: email, ssl, certificate, blocking

Is it possible for a company, ISP, or other entity to block any website that uses certificates issued by, say, *Let's Encrypt*?

My boss seems to think that all the times that our emails weren't getting through in years past is due to the fact that a CA we use for our mail server's certificates was being blocked. I am pretty sure he's conflating domain blocking with certificates, but please inform me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by blocked? Do you mean being rejected or marked as spam?

Comment: One could absolutely not trust a specific certificate authority.  However, any certificate signed by that authority, would also not be trusted.  If your server only allows signed emails (by a certificate it trusts to be delivered), only does that theory make sense

Comment: There seems to be two different issues here. The question in the first paragraph talks about "websites", so, presumably HTTPS. The second paragraph however talks about mail server, so, presumably SMTP over TLS or STARTTLS. Which one is it? For HTTPS, most CA certificates come embedded in browsers and most people don't tamper with that. For SMTP, a mail server can easily be configured to reject certificates signed by particular CAs.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses and answers. It's all good information, but to be honest, most of it goes over my head. @HermógenesOliveira: You are correct that there is confusion. It stems from both myself and my boss not knowing exactly how certs work, but he makes assumptions about them. Neither of us wants to know all the deep details of their inner workings; I just wanted to see if it was feasible for all traffic (mail/http(s)/whatever) to be blocked based on the cert issuer.

Comment: I think my boss' worry stems from incidents in the past when our emails were not getting delivered to some of our customers. We were placed on some sort of blacklist, mistakenly thinking we were spammers. Again, I maintain that this has nothing to do with certs; that our domain name was caught in a roundup of sorts of spammers. He's worried that if we use Let's Encrypt for our websites' certs, that some ISPs or companies may choose to not trust LE and block all sites that use LE as their cert issuer because it's free.

Comment: It finally happened. A few customers complained about our web site and now my boss thinks Let's Encrypt is the devil and will never consider using them again. Excerpt from a customer's email: "When I try to access any webpage except for your home page, it is blocked, saying it is not a secure connection. Several of my colleagues have tried as well and have the same issue (various browsers too)." Boss is convinced that they are blocking Let's Encrypt certificates and that's why not all of the pages load on the site. He's now paying thousands for "real" certs.

Answer (score 0):

CAs are, at the heart of it, accepted or denied by *programs* that make connections to peers/servers using TLS.  The program can automatically accept, automatically deny, or prompt the user to accept/deny, or behave a given way depending on things in the certificate like expiration date, issuer, etc.

Operating systems and crypto libraries provide frameworks for programs to make a decision, on both ends (the initiating end/the receiving end).

The exact behavior depends on the program and the operating system/library involved.

A program might ask you before accepting or denying a connection that uses a particular  CA for various reasons.

Typical reasons for a program to *not* automatically accept connections from a CA (either deny or ask you if it's OK to proceed) are:

- Operating system/program maintains a repository/list of trusted CAs and the CA presented by the website is not in that repository/list.
- Operating system/program maintains a repository/list of revoked CAs and the CA presented by the website is in that repository/list.

  - Some programs can use a "certificate revocation list" and will refuse connections from certificates that appear on that list.
- Operating system/program uses a protocol such as OCSP to check the status of a certificate and gets an answer saying that the certificate is invalid, or gets no answer.
- CA certificate is expired.
- Program is set to trust a certificate for only specified amount of time and that time has passed.

A lot of times error messages won't differentiate between the above situations.

> a CA we use for our mail server's certificates was being blocked

So this in practical terms can mean the certificates were expired, the root CA was marked as untrusted by major vendors (eg. Diginotar), or something like that.  If a CA is believed to be compromised, operating system and browser vendors will remove it from trusted root stores.  This is effectively blocking.

Answer (score 0):

"Is it possible for a company, ISP, or other entity to block any website that uses certificates issued by, say, Let's Encrypt?* - **No**

There are some caveats, but they are all fairly niche/specialised.   First I'll explain why the answer is no, then explore the exceptions -

Accepted Certificate authority keys are stored locally, ie Firefox or Chrome or anything using CA infrastructure makes use of the CA public keys shipped with the OS or browser. The whole reason there are limited CAs is because of the negotiations required to get the CA certs to the client.  **this means that there is no communication between the client and the CA** (and the server only talks to the CA to replace its cert occasionally and sometimes manually). **so there is nothing an ISP can block.**

There are some exceptions/edge cases - If an ISP could inject their own CA cert into yourbcert bundle, then they could perform a MITM attack on encrypted traffic and block it that way.

It would be very out the mainstream, but an ISP could possibly MITM your communications and see what sites you are talking to (even though the communication is encrypted its likely the ISP can still deduce the party based in IP address or data used to negotiate the https/TLS session. They could then look up the sites address and block it.   This is something they would need to go out of their way to do - and blocking based on CA sounds stupid - because by the time the blocking decision is made they have invested heavily on tools which can block more precisely and more easily.

Another possibility is your cert is not correctly/ideally installed and that could cause some blocking - for example unsupported cyphers, different TLS levels, intermediate CA issues, date related issues.  None of these would be related to ISP blocking though.